# How to fix error “ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python.” when trying to install FOMMRIA

Tags: python

I am trying to install [FOMMRIA](https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model) using pip but it keeps running into an error.

I haven't found anything specific to my problem, so I'm hoping I can get some help here. I'm starting to think it's my computer, but either-either, I'm hoping to find some answers.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Error:

```
Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP Pavilion\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dy3_jska\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP Pavilion\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dy3_jska\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dy3_jska\matplotlib\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\HP Pavilion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dy3_jska\matplotlib\
    Complete output (61 lines):
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.2]
                    python: yes [3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020,
                            23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]
                  platform: yes [win32]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                            (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                            need to install the development package.]
                       png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: yes [installing]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]
```